# Is CAPM + additions actually used in industry-level portfolio optimization?

Tags: portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, capm

I've been wondering how do institutional investors actually perform portfolio optimization, i.e., do the traditional methods work when combined together with superior data collections and quality, and state-of-art optimization methods? Simple example would be CAPM + additions + GARCH models. You can go very complex or very simple here, but the idea is the same. What statistical models could be considered?

Comment: As you say, it can be very complex or very simple - but the idea is not the same. Depends on the fund, their objectives, mandates and the time scales they operate at.

Comment: Do you have any examples?